# sorting a php array alphanumerically

Tags: php, sorting

I know there are natsort() and natcasesort() functions in php to sort array elements in natural order. I am trying to sort the following items.

```
 array[0]= '10. xyz';
   array[1]=  '13. xyz';
   array[2]=  '2. xyz';
   array[3]=  '1a. xyz';
   array[4]=  '6. xyz';
   array[5]=  '1b. xyz';
   array[6]=  '4a. xyz';
   array[7]=  '4b. xyz';
```

now if I apply natsort(), '10..' and '13..' are placed above '1a..'. how can I make my php code to think that '10..' is greater than '1a...' and '1a...' should be at the top? the correct output in my particular case is:

```
'1a. xyz';
'1b. xyz';
'2. xyz';
'4a. xyz';
'4b. xyz';
'6. xyz';
'10. xyz';
'13. xyz';
```

i used a custom algo but it does the same...it places '10..' before '1a...'. heres my custom func:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a_ex=explode(".",$a);
    $b_ex=explode(".",$b);
    if ($a_ex[0] == $b_ex[0] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_ex[0] < $b_ex[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: As others have posted, `natsort()` works for me. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use natsort():

```
$array[0]= '10. xyz';
$array[1]=  '13. xyz';
$array[2]=  '2. xyz';
$array[3]=  '1a. xyz';
$array[4]=  '6. xyz';
$array[5]=  '1b. xyz';
$array[6]=  '4a. xyz';
$array[7]=  '4b. xyz';

natsort($array);

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

natsort works fine for me...

Otherwise use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-pad.php) to format the numbers before you sort the array.

Or you can user [usort](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) with a custom function, maybe with intval...

Answer (score 0):

use [usort](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) with your own custom algorithm

Comment: natsort() present algorithm for it.