# Sorting array of strings by contained numbers?

Tags: php, sorting

I have those elements in an array:

```
/mypath/10_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/1_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/12_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/2_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/3_something_04_06.txt
```

Now I want to sort it, so that the numbers after `/mypath/` are considered. This is what I tried:

```
sort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
sort($myArray, SORT_STRING );
```

It doesn't work. 
Should be expected result like below:

```
/mypath/1_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/2_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/3_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/10_something_04_06.txt
/mypath/12_something_04_06.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, thats the one, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting a php array alphanumerically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295819/sorting-a-php-array-alphanumerically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) (Sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm)

Comment: This is pretty much a link only answer at the moment. Care to flesh it out a little more than this?

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution, its just a one liner though :).